# Android Sqlite with ContentProvider or SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I was working around with android db and met 2 methods of working:

1) Using just `SqliteOpenHelper`

2) Using `ContentProvider` and `SqliteOpenHelper`

Is there any advantage using one or other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is primarily opinion based, but to sum it up:

> 1) Using just SqliteOpenHelper

You will have to manage the db access yourself. Provide methods for CRUD access and have full control. Updates can and should still be handled with `SqliteOpenHelper`.

> 2) Using ContentProvider and SqliteOpenHelper

This will give you access to your db via framework methods. It will enable you to use `CursorLoader` (automatic refresh on change), `SyncAdapter` (sync changes to a server), and some other features right out of the box. You will have to work with `URI` paths to identify your elements and post queries, since you have no *direct* access to the database.
This option is better documented, since it is an official android api, albeit you will have to do some reading before you can optimally use it.

---

Also worth noting, if some other developer looks at your code, they will probably know how to use your `ContentProvider` (if you keep it consistent) but they will have to read into your source code (or documentation) to find out how to use your custom implementation.

Comment: to make sure, are you saying that it is impossible/hard to use SyncAdapter with just SqliteOpenHelper?

Comment: @Nazerke SyncAdapter as part of the framework are intended to use with a content provider and I believe most tutorials will also use them. Obviously you don't have to use a ContentProvider, but I myself hate working against the framework.